# Asp.Net HtmlBeginForm() Jquery submit does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, forms, http-post

I want to display a partial view by using Ajax, after the form is submitted. I need to listen for a submit event, and then fire Ajax to display a partial view. Note: I do not need to submit a form by using JQuery or Ajax, I just need to catch that event and fire Ajax.

However, the JQuery function $("form").submit() does not work!

I've put a breakpoint in Chrome debugger and it is not even fired. What is the problem? Here is the code:

P.S. The form consists of comboboxes where user can select application name and version, then charts of performance testing results will be displayed as partial view using Ajax.

```html
@model PerformanceDashboard.Models.ApplicationDashboardViewModel

<h3>Per Application</h3>


<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{ 
   // @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            
    <div class="selector-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationNames)
    </div>

    <div class="selector-combobox">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedApplication, Model.ApplicationNames)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedApplication)   
     </div>

    <br />
    
    <div class="selector-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestingTypes)
    </div>

    <div class="selector-combobox">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedTestingType, Model.TestingTypes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedTestingType)
    </div>

    <br />
    
    <div class="selector-label">
        @Html.Label("Range")
    </div>

    <div class="selector-combobox">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFirstVersion, Model.FirstVersion)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedFirstVersion)
        &nbsp;
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedSecondVersion, Model.SecondVersion)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedSecondVersion)
    </div>
    
    <br />
    
    <input type="submit" value="Generate" />
    
}

<div id="displayarea">

</div>


<script>

    $(function () {

        $("#form").submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            alert("form submitted!");

            $.ajax({
                type: this.method, //'POST'
                url: this.action, //'/controller/index'
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#displayarea').html(result);
                }
            });
        })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: try another id other than (form)

Comment: Should work, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caaL602x/2/). Post your html for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG!!
The problem was that I did not reference JQuery in HTML! 
This line solved my problem:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Thanks!